# Javascript add all values with similar fileld name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table as below

```
------------------------------------
|      Date      |       Price     | 
------------------------------------
|   09-13-2017   |       $15.00    |
|   09-13-2017   |       $6.00     |
|   09-15-2017   |       $8.00     |
|   09-15-2017   |       $14.50    |
|__________________________________|
```

I want to sum the total values of each **Date** so the output would be

```
Total value for 09-13-2017 is $21.00
Total value for 09-15-2017 is $22.50
```

How do i do this in JavaScript. Kindly guide.

```
var dat = jQuery("#date").map(function()
    {
        totpri = 0;
        var pri = jQuery("#price").map(function()
        {
            var totpri = document.getElementByID("price").value();
            totpri += totpri;
        }
        alert('The Total is: ' totpri)
    }).get();
```

Comment: What sort of table is that? An ASCII Art table? A PostgreSQL table? An HTML table?

Comment: Show what you've done so far

Comment: Where is this JavaScript supposed to run? In Node.js? In Windows Scripting Host? As an Adobe Photoshop plugin? As a Firefox extension? Somewhere else?

Comment: It is a HTML table. each value can have their own ID.

Comment: What research have you done? Your question currently reads as something more suitable for hiring a freelancer than one from someone looking for help with their own programming.

Comment: If its an HTML table, why are you showing us an ASCII art table instead of HTML source code?

Comment: Sorry guys. I have added the code i tried now. Kindly guide.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you tried? Provide a *clear problem statement*

Comment: Hi Quentin I just want to sum the answers like how i explained. Can you help?

Answer (score -1):

I can give you a technique you can use but not the code ( since I don't see your effort )

**Step 1**: create an empty associative array (say arrDates)

**Step 2:** Iterate through each row and check if the array contains a key  with the keyname as 1st column(date)

If NOT => create a new entry in the format: {'date' => amount}

If YES => get the old amount for that date, and add the current amount to it, update the amount in the array

That's it

Now you can iterate this array and display the dates and amount sum in whatever format you want

Comment: Thanks you mrid. Ihave added the code now. Can you help?